# Hibernate is joining a table that I didn't asked for

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE_PARENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class DDParent implements Serializable
{
```

And this other

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE_CHILD")
public class DDChild extends DDParent implements Serializable
{
```

This is how I run the query

```
FROM DDParent s WHERE s.customerPk = ?
```

So my issue is that hibernate is joining a table I didn't asked for.
I see the following in the logs.

```
10:30:08,809 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (http-0.0.0.0:8081-1) 
select 
  ddsubscrip0_.order_pk as order_pk1_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.created_ts as created_2_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.customer_pk as customer3_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.expiration_dt as expirati4_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.initial_quantity as initial_5_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.last_modified_ts as last_mod6_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.product_cd as product_7_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.remaining_quantity as remainin8_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.start_dt as start_dt9_6_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.billingContact as billingC1_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.payment_ty_cd as payment_2_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.run_vin_in as run_vin_3_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.site_id as site_id4_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.total_price as total_pr5_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.total_tax as total_ta6_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.transaction_ts as transact7_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.upsell_ty_desc as upsell_t8_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.upsell_ty_cd as upsell_t9_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.vin as vin10_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.voucher_cd as voucher11_5_, 
  ddsubscrip0_.clazz_ as clazz_ 
from 
  (
    select 
      order_pk, 
      created_ts, 
      customer_pk, 
      expiration_dt, 
      initial_quantity, 
      last_modified_ts, 
      product_cd, 
      remaining_quantity, 
      start_dt, 
      nullif(0, 0) as billingContact, 
      nullif(0, 0) as payment_ty_cd, 
      nullif(0, 0) as run_vin_in, 
      nullif('x', 'x') as site_id, 
      nullif(0, 0) as total_price, 
      nullif(0, 0) as total_tax, 
      nullif(
        '2000-1-1 00:00:00', '2000-1-1 00:00:00'
      ) as transaction_ts, 
      nullif('x', 'x') as upsell_ty_desc, 
      nullif(0, 0) as upsell_ty_cd, 
      nullif('x', 'x') as vin, 
      nullif('x', 'x') as voucher_cd, 
      0 as clazz_ 
    from 
      DD_PARENT 
    union all 
    select 
      order_pk, 
      created_ts, 
      customer_pk, 
      expiration_dt, 
      initial_quantity, 
      last_modified_ts, 
      product_cd, 
      remaining_quantity, 
      start_dt, 
      billingContact, 
      payment_ty_cd, 
      run_vin_in, 
      site_id, 
      total_price, 
      total_tax, 
      transaction_ts, 
      upsell_ty_desc, 
      upsell_ty_cd, 
      vin, 
      voucher_cd, 
      1 as clazz_ 
    from 
      DD_CHILD
  ) ddsubscrip0_ 
where 
  ddsubscrip0_.customer_pk = ?
```

I don't want it to join the child table or select its fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the hibernate behavior in this case: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism

To solve your problem, you can use `polymorphism="explicit"` in your class mapping: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html